# Jquery validation and localization in symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, symfony

I want to display messages in poth two langage, English and French, but I can't do it, it display just french messages.

how I can perform localization in jquery in symfony 2:

this is my code
in twig

```
 <form id="formulaire"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="full_form" action="{{ path('add_contact') }}" method="post" >
 <div class="left small_width">

                {{ form_widget(form.name,{ 'attr': {'label':'nom','maxlength': '50','placeholder':'placeholder.nom'|trans} }) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.lastName, { 'attr': {'maxlength': '50','placeholder':'placeholder.prenom'|trans} }) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.listcountry,{ 'attr': {'maxlength': '50','placeholder':'placeholder.contact.country'|trans} }) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.gsmPrimary, { 'attr': {'maxlength': '50','placeholder':'placeholder.contact.gsmPrimary'|trans} }) }}
     </div>           
</form>

{%block javascript %}
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#formulaire').validate({ // initialize the plugin

            onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                'contact[name]': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                'contact[gsmPrimary]': {
                    required: true,
                    'regexphone': /^0[1-9][0-9]{8}$/
                },

            },
            messages: {

                'contact[name]': {
                    required: "Veuillez renseigner votre nom.",
                    minlength: "Votre nom doit faire au moins 6 caractères.",
                    maxlength: "Votre nom doit faire au plus 50 caractères."
                },

                'contact[gsmPrimary]': {
                    required: "Veuillez renseigner votre tél. mobile.",
                    'regexphone': "test"
                },

            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: you do it like any regular localization, if its inside twig template use trans filter.

Comment: I tied that but does not work

Comment: Post your complete code. All u need is translate your strings here like Votre nom doit faire au moins 6 caractères., correct? Post your code, how u are doing it in twig

Comment: the code was updated

Comment: Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your javascript messages in twig at all, you need to do this in twig:

```
 required: "{{ yourmessage1|trans }}.",
 minlength: "{{ minlength|trans }}",
```

Or if you want to use a specific translation file or domain:

```
required: "{{ yourmessage2|trans({},'yourDomain') }}.",
```

yourmessage1, and yourmessage2 string should be in your translation files. Like for example in a message.en.yml:

```
yourmessage1: This is my message it will be displayed inside jquery
yourmessage2: Another message it will be displayed inside jquery
```

Read on [Symfony translation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/translation.html)